# Query items in database with linq from Guid List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a `List<Guid>() list = new List<Guid()` with many Guid's.

How to use this list against database and fetch all elements from Database where their ID is in that list of Guid's with LINQ?

I tryed `Any()` and `Contains()` but never seemed to do the right job, raising:

```
"...this method cannot be translated into a store expression..."
```

Try number one with Contains:

```
List<Foo> listF = db.Foo
                    .Where(s => list.Contains(s.ID))
                    .Select(r => r)
                    .ToList<Foo>();
```

Try number two with Any:

```
List<Bar> listB = db.Bar
                     .Where(s => list.Any(srch => s.ID == srch))
                     .Select(r => r)
                     .ToList<Bar>();
```

Thanks

EDIT:

The previous code was for making it easier to explain. The list of Guids is used as a container to add multiple elements to specific element in a one to Many relation, in this case, add Bar to Foo.

the actual code:

```
     public override async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Exclude = "Creation_Entity,Last_Update_Entity, Guid, ID, Creation_Date, Last_Update_Date, Deactivated")] List<Foo> list)
            {
    //Foo_GuidList is a list of Guid inside object Foo that will correspond to Bar elements in db

                if (list[0].Foo_GuidList.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<Bar> listB = PageContext_Configs.db.Bar
                                      .Where(s => list[0].Foo_GuidList.Any(srch => s.ID == srch))
                                 //or .Where(s => list[0].Foo_GuidList.Contains(s.ID))
                                      .Select(r => r)
                                      .ToList<Bar>();
                }
```

When I was posting the actual code, as sugestion of Dennis, I found the problem... EF can't deal with list[0]. When red Guru Stron comment it made the click. So, I just did `List<Guid> listTemp = list[0].Foo_GuidList;` as suggested and used it with `Contains()` and voilá... Rookie mistake by me!

Comment: `Contains` does the work - usually it's being translated into `IN` SQL condition. Please show your *real* code. Note, that `Select` in your samples is superfluous, because it results to the same object as was passed.

Comment: Is `db.Foo.ID` property also GUID?

Comment: Yes, db.Foo.ID is also a GUID.

Comment: try casting to enumerable `var listEn  = list.AsEnumerable()` and `db.Foo.Where(s => listEn.Contains(s.ID))`. Some EF versions had troubles with lists in this context.

Comment: Found the problem... Both Dennis and Guru Stron comments led me to the answer. Edited the question with actual code and why it wasnt working. If you put it in an answer I will make it the answer. Thank you and sorry for the trouble